# Netsuite: Merge scripts using bundles from one account to another

Tags: netsuite

I have some client scripts in one account. Is it possible to merge scripts of one account into another account using bundle installation.

Answer (score 0):

Not automatically and not via SuiteBundle. Whenever you install a bundle, associated files (images, text, scripts) of the bundle are copied to your NetSuite's file cabinet to path "SuiteBundles\Bundles NNNN" where NNNN is the bundle id. If you have an existing customer user event script customer.js (inside SuiteScript folder) and you installed a bundle with another customer user event script with js file named customer.js as well, there will not be any conflict since the 2 files are located in 2 different locations.

Only way is for you to manually merge the scripts that but would entail hours of coding and I would advise against it unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: so what do you recommend

Comment: I dont want to overwrite changes from account 1 to account 2... I already have some script changes in account 2. So I only want to merge account 1 changes into account 2 script no overwrite.

Comment: Can’t the 2 scripts run in parallel? If you really want to merge the script, you need to do it manually.